# 360 degree feedback: free or open-source software available?

Tags: open-source

Has anyone used a free or open-source software product to run [360 degree feedback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360-degree_feedback) for employee reviews?

My company wants to implement a process and has asked me to build a small web application to administer it and track the responses. Before I build something, I thought I should look for what others have built.

I'll post answers with the two candidates I've found so far, but neither of them look very promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, but there's also PiiQ from cornerstone, which is web-based and charged per-user so the pricing scales quite easily. https://smb.cornerstoneondemand.com/piiq

Comment: That looks pretty slick. $9 per person is way cheaper than building something. I'll have to poke around and see if it's got all the features we want. We did a manual process this year, but we might try this product next year.

Comment: Dead link these days

Answer (score -1):

Somebody built a proof-of-concept at [Open Universiteit Nederland](http://dspace.ou.nl/handle/1820/1111), but it doesn't seem finished. I'm guessing it was a research project that got abandoned. Might make a good starting point, but the Eclipse platform isn't a great fit for what I want to do.

Answer (score -1):

[quick360](http://www.reactive360.com/quick360.html) is a free web app that lets you send predefined questionnaires to your employees. You can't edit the questions. There are paid versions that let you do more.